# single function inside function doesn't fire, while others do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a strange behavior of my [`main.js`](http://tobiasgla.us/main.js) (maybe it's not strange and I'm just doing a stupid mistake).
So I got a function `$(function(){...});` with a few other function in it. Check out my code:

```
$(function() {

    // THIS FUNCTION DOES FIRE
    setInterval(function() { 
        var active = $(".active").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        if (active.next() && active.next().length) {
            active.next().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        } else {
            active.siblings(":first").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        }
    }, 3000);

    // THAT WORKS ASWELL
    var sectionHeight = $(".welcome-page").outerHeight();
    $(".abilities-page").css('height', sectionHeight);
    $(".portfolio-page").css('height', sectionHeight);
    var titleAlign = sectionHeight / 2 - $(".sectiontitle").outerHeight() / 2;
    $(".sectiontitle").css('padding-top', titleAlign);

    $(".logo").addClass('logoVis');
    // ALL OF THAT WORKS UNTIL HERE

    // THIS WHOLE FUNCTION DOES NOT FIRE
    $(function($) {
        $(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                $('div.section').removeClass('most-visible').mostVisible().addClass('most-visible');
                $(function() {
                    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
                        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
                        $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
                            var vpHeight = $(window).height();
                            var scrollOffset = (vpHeight - sectionHeight) / 2;
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("div.most-visible").offset().top -
                                    scrollOffset
                            }, 500);
                        }, 1000));
                        if ($(window).width() > 900) {
                            if ($(window).scrollTop() >=
                                $(document).height() -
                                $(window).height() - 20 || $(window).scrollTop() <= 20) {
                                $("footer").addClass('footerVis');
                                $(".logo").addClass('logoVis');
                                $('html, body').stop(true);
                            } else {
                                $("footer").removeClass('footerVis');
                                $(".logo").removeClass('logoVis');
                            }
                        } else {
                            $("footer").addClass('footerVis');
                            $(".logo").addClass('logoVis');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });

        function getMostVisible($elements) {
            var $element = $(),
                viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
                max = 0;

            $elements.each(function() {
                var visiblePx = getVisibleHeightPx($(this), viewportHeight);

                if (visiblePx > max) {
                    max = visiblePx;
                    $element = $(this);
                }
            });

            return $element;
        }

        function getVisibleHeightPx($element, viewportHeight) {
            var rect = $element.get(0).getBoundingClientRect(),
                height = rect.bottom - rect.top,
                visible = {
                    top: rect.top >= 0 && rect.top < viewportHeight,
                    bottom: rect.bottom > 0 && rect.bottom < viewportHeight
                },
                visiblePx = 0;

            if (visible.top && visible.bottom) {
                // Whole element is visible
                visiblePx = height;
            } else if (visible.top) {
                visiblePx = viewportHeight - rect.top;
            } else if (visible.bottom) {
                visiblePx = rect.bottom;
            } else if (height > viewportHeight && rect.top < 0) {
                var absTop = Math.abs(rect.top);

                if (absTop < height) {
                    // Part of the element is visible
                    visiblePx = height - absTop;
                }
            }

            return visiblePx;
        }

    });

    // THAT WORKS ASWELL
    $("#item1").animatedModal({
        modalTarget: 'animatedModal1',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8);'
    });

});
```

As you can see, I added some comment to mark, which parts do work and which don't. It's just a single function, which doesn't work.

- The console is not giving me any errors.
- latest version of jQuery is embedded
- all other JS-files work flawlessly

To check out my full website or the belonging CSS, HTML, etc. code go to:

- [tobiasgla.us](http://tobiasgla.us/) for the full website
- [tobiasgla.us/main.js](http://tobiasgla.us/main.js) for the full JS file
- [tobiasgla.us/style.css](http://tobiasgla.us/style.css) for the CSS

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Just FYI, `$(function($) {})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Comment: You had many suggestions already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049917/add-removeclass-doesnt-work-anymore

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, I'm aware of that.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus and still `$(function($) {
        $(function() {`. Nice.

Comment: @Morpheus Yes, punkbit spent alot of time trying to help me, but nothing worked :/

Comment: Place the tidied javascript to your website initially ->  https://jsfiddle.net/gmy2k1bv/ and see if problems persist

Comment: @Morpheus It does. Check out my [site](http://tobiasgla.us/). I changed the `main.js` according to your tidied code and it's looking and behaving the same way like before

Comment: The `setInterval` function does fire, just wait 3 seconds; scroll event doesn't fire because you have `overflow-x: hidden;` css attached to your body and html

Comment: and disabling that style then scroll causes an error "mostVisible is not a function" ...

Comment: just a 10 second look at the codepen found in your other question shows you didn't copy $.fn.mostVisible = function() { ... }

Comment: **Thanks to everyone!** @Morpheus and @yezzz did the trick. I guess I accidentally deleted the line, where I return the most visible section. I added that on my website and removed the `overflow-x: hidden`. Working like a charm now! You can have a fight now, who writes an answer and get some free reputation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem with help of @Morpheus and @yezzz from the comments. The problem was that I accidentaly removed an important line from the JS:

```
$.fn.mostVisible = function() {
  return getMostVisible(this);
}
```

Adding that again from [my codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/VbzJWB) and removing

```
body,html{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

from the CSS did the trick :) Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will help but I see an issue with the nested window scroll event binding. Maybe try this version without all the extra $(functions)() and without the nested window.on('scroll')

```
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var $footer = $("footer");
  var $logo = $(".logo");

  // THIS FUNCTION DOES FIRE
  setInterval(function() { 
      var active = $(".active").fadeOut(1000, function() {
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      });
      if (active.next() && active.next().length) {
          active.next().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
              $(this).addClass('active');
          });
      } else {
          active.siblings(":first").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
              $(this).addClass('active');
          });
      }
  }, 3000);

  // THAT WORKS ASWELL
  var sectionHeight = $(".welcome-page").outerHeight();
  $(".abilities-page").css('height', sectionHeight);
  $(".portfolio-page").css('height', sectionHeight);
  var titleAlign = sectionHeight / 2 - 
  $(".sectiontitle").outerHeight() / 2;
  $(".sectiontitle").css('padding-top', titleAlign);

  $logo.addClass('logoVis');
  // ALL OF THAT WORKS UNTIL HERE

  // THIS WHOLE FUNCTION DOES NOT FIRE


  $window.scroll(function() {
      $('div.section').removeClass('most-visible').mostVisible().addClass('most-visible');

      clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
      $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
          var vpHeight = $window.height();
          var scrollOffset = (vpHeight - sectionHeight) / 2;
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("div.most-visible").offset().top -
                  scrollOffset
          }, 500);
      }, 1000));

      if ($window.width() > 900) {
          if ($window.scrollTop() >=
              $(document).height() -
              $window.height() - 20 || $(window).scrollTop() <= 20) {
              $footer.addClass('footerVis');
              $logo.addClass('logoVis');
              $('html, body').stop(true);
          } else {
              $footer.removeClass('footerVis');
              $logo.removeClass('logoVis');
          }
      } else {
          $footer.addClass('footerVis');
          $logo.addClass('logoVis');
      }
  });

  function getMostVisible($elements) {
      var $element = $(),
          viewportHeight = $(window).height(),
          max = 0;

      $elements.each(function() {
          var visiblePx = getVisibleHeightPx($(this), viewportHeight);

          if (visiblePx > max) {
              max = visiblePx;
              $element = $(this);
          }
      });

      return $element;
  }

  function getVisibleHeightPx($element, viewportHeight) {
      var rect = $element.get(0).getBoundingClientRect(),
          height = rect.bottom - rect.top,
          visible = {
              top: rect.top >= 0 && rect.top < viewportHeight,
              bottom: rect.bottom > 0 && rect.bottom < viewportHeight
          },
          visiblePx = 0;

      if (visible.top && visible.bottom) {
          // Whole element is visible
          visiblePx = height;
      } else if (visible.top) {
          visiblePx = viewportHeight - rect.top;
      } else if (visible.bottom) {
          visiblePx = rect.bottom;
      } else if (height > viewportHeight && rect.top < 0) {
          var absTop = Math.abs(rect.top);

          if (absTop < height) {
              // Part of the element is visible
              visiblePx = height - absTop;
          }
      }

      return visiblePx;
  }

  // THAT WORKS ASWELL
  $("#item1").animatedModal({
      modalTarget: 'animatedModal1',
      overflow: 'hidden',
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8);'
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you copied the code from the fiddle I added in comments? :)

Comment: Oh no, sorry did not notice your fiddle js, notice how I started caching his jquery selectors and then gave up :P I would have commented but can't right now :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found out the problem. As I mentioned. It's not weird behavior. I guess I accidentaly deleted a line from my codepen (where I originally made that thing).